# Node Failure Detection/Reporting in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, detection

In addition to use Cassandra as a distributed NoSQL data store, we are interested in using it to maintain node up/down status for a cluster. Is there a way to get to the list of "active" or "up" nodes (as maintained by Cassandra) so our application may take care of the application-specific (non-Cassandra) cleaning for those recently failed nodes? Obviously we also need to do the application-specific node initialization when a failed node later on recovers.  We assume that Cassandra has a stringent approach in maintaining its nodes and want to take advantage of that instead of doing that ourselves.

Comment: Would JMX provides what we want?  Any details if yes?

Comment: I suppose nodetool ring would give me what I want.